# Google Signin for iOS No Longer Using Google App

Tags: google-signin

So I recently updated the Google Signin API to 2.3.1 (and then 2.3.2 today) and ever since, my app no longer bounces me to the installed Google app for authentication. It instead always opens a web view in the app.

What changes have caused this?

To be clear, nothing is broken and sign in works just fine. In fact, it looks like the user doesn't need to enter a password if they are already signed in which is great. Still, why the change?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, i have YouTube, G+, etc. installed & signed in but it still opens a safari webview.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on iOS9? I believe this is intentional. The team ended up changing the default behavior of the Google Sign-in library on iOS9 to prefer an embedded Safari View Controller. The rationale being that an embedded SFSafariViewController is probably a better overall experience on iOS9, and it's more reviewer-friendly.

If you really want to switch to a native app, you can add the line

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = false
```

to your app, and it won't use webviews, but I really wouldn't recommend changing the default behavior unless you feel like it's really necessary.

Comment: I tried setting         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = false and combinations of those, but no dice... iOS9.1

Comment: This does not appear to be possible on iOS 10, SDK version 4.0.1. Is that correct?

Comment: @gmat1014, quite possibly. I think with more modern versions of they SDK, they'd like to move away from the WebView entirely, since the SFSafariViewController is more secure and a better experience overall.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I see. And there doesn't seem to be any public APIs to configure the SDK to use a Google App (if available). I've downloaded and authenticated with Google Maps, the Google Search app and Gmail and it never deep links to those apps for auth. It only uses the SFSafariViewController.

Comment: @gmat1014 Yes that is correct, GoogleSignIn 4.0.0 removed allowsSignInWithWebView and allowsSignInWithBrowser